# How do I deploy react + GraphQL to Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, graphql, apollo

I have a full stack application that uses React on the frontend and GraphQL yoga on the backend. I am trying to deploy the app to Heroku, but I can't get my frontend to be served. When I go to the Heroku URL all I see is the GraphQL playground.

Here is what I have that starts my server:

```js
const options = {
        port: process.env.PORT || 4000
      }

    server.start(options, ({ port }) =>
        console.log(
            `Server started, listening on port ${port} for incoming requests.`,
        ),
    )
```

On the frontend I have this which connects it to my server:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000"
})
```

But I don't know how to get this all running on Heroku.

Comment: Are you including uri: "http://localhost:4000" in your frontend when posting it into heroku too ?

Comment: What do you mean including it? Do you mean like a special configuration? Sorry I've never deployed to Heroku before

Comment: If you set the uri as `(const client = new ApolloClient({uri: "http://localhost:4000"}))` it wouldn't work on heroku because your server app is not running on localhost:4000 of heroku. Also are you trying to serve the react page using the same graphql server ?

Comment: Oh, yes I do have that in my client. What should I change it to? And yes I am trying to serve the react page using the server, unless there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your apolloClient uri to:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "/graphql"
})
```

then deploy it again.

If you are using create-react-app, you should add proxy for your client for **Development** use:

In your setupProxy.js file:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/',
    { target: 'http://localhost:4000' } //your server
    ));
}
```

Hope it helps.